# why does `innerText` property does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, innertext

Why does `var a = e.target.innerText` does not work but if I set `var a = e.target` and then do `if(a.innerText == "")` it works. Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv8ma4og/1/) of my code and a snippet bellow:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".boxes");
const turn = "X";

boxes.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var a = e.target.innerText;

    if (a == "") {
      a = turn;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.boxes {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 3em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div><br>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div><br>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
            <div class="boxes"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks:

> Why does var a = e.target.innerText does not work but if I set var a = e.target and then do if(a.innerText == "") [it does]

e.target gives you an element.

e.target.innerText gives you the inner text of the element e.target. It is text, it is not itself a reference to that text.

So when you set the JS variable a = e.target.innerText and then set a = 'X', it is the JS variable that is set to that text, not the innerText of the element.

It may help (or may add confusion, I'm not sure) to read up about call by reference versus value etc e.g. at [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```js
if (a == "") {
  a = turn;
}
```

you should do

```js
if (a == "") {
  e.target.innerText = turn;
}
```

Comment: I am asking why does this happen.

Comment: What you're doing is first assigning `e.target.innerText` to the variable `a`, and then changing the variable `a`. You're not changing what you want. You may think that you've somehow linked them together, but no, string is a primitive in JavaScript, and primitives are copied rather than shared by references, and they cannot be mutated either.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `var a = e.target.innerText;` gets only the string inside the element `<div class="boxes"></div>` and assigns to the variable 'a', then you are just changing the variable 'a' instead of changing the `div`'s innerText.

So `var a = e.target` works because it gets the element instead of just only the string. Then you can change the `div`'s innerText with,

```
if (a.innerText == "") {
    a.innerText = turn;
}
```